# How to remove everything after a keyword is matched?

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match, php-5.3

How can I use `preg_replace` to remove everything after a keyword is matched?

For instance, if the keyword `local` is matched in the string below,

```
home/hello/local/flower/stone/...
```

then return this only,

```
home/hello
```

or can I use any php default array function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, a simple `strpos + strlen` could do the trick.

```
<?php

$string = "hello/local/flower/stone/...";
$keyword = "local";

echo substr($string, 0, strpos($string, $keyword));

?>
```

http://ideone.com/3OOq8

Be careful, I assumed that you'll always have your keyword in the String, that might not be the case.

---

**Resources:**

- [php.net - strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)
- [php.net - strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)
- [php.net - substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: My bad, I just saw your comment below, remove the strlen part to remove the keyword too. I just updated it, but you will probably want to play more with the substr to adjust the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = 'hello/local/flower/stone/...';
$find = 'local';
$replaced = preg_replace("#(.*?{$find}).*#", '$1', $str);
var_dump($replaced);
?>
```

Comment: If you want to do it with regex (absolutely not recommanded) I suggest you to add preg_quote (just in case)

Comment: I ran into the problem once where the replacement string contained unintended back-references. http://ak.net84.net/php/the-horrors-of-using-preg_replace/

Comment: In that case you'd make it `#(.*?){$find}.*#`

Comment: THanks Aram for the answer! :-)